# Is there a way to have typescript infer the type for each individual index of an array without having the type parameter in the function?

Tags: typescript

The title is probably confusing, I wasn't sure how to properly word it but in short I'd like to accomplish the following:

```ts
type A<T extends new (...args: any) => any = any> = [T, Required<InstanceType<T>>];

function b<T extends new (...args: any) => any, T2 extends new (...args: any) => any>(...args: [A<T>, A<T2>?]) { };

class C { d?: string; e?: number };

class F { g?: string; h?: number };

b([C, { d: '', e: 2 }], [F, { g: '', h: 3 }]);
```

But without having to have the `T, T2` type parameters in the `b` function, since in my use case, the function wouldn't have a defined length for the parameters. Is this possible? If not are there better solutions to this?

Comment: Maybe the new variadic tuple types in TS4.0 could help: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html
there's also this which contains some of what you want I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872328/infer-tuple-type-instead-of-union-type

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I had a look at the links but couldn't figure out what exactly applies to my case here.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking to make `b` take an arbitrary number of parameters of type `A`, which is itself parametric, then unfortunately no. There *might* be a hacky way of doing so, but it would certainly not be clean and probably rely on a recursive type to handle enforcing that the 2nd member of the array is type-checked based on the 1st.

The core problem is that Typescript doesn't support higher kinded types. So what you need is something that can parameterize over `Array<T>` where `T` is parameterized over `A<K>`. This would mean needing a function, `b`, that looks like so

```
export declare function b<T extends A<K>[]>(...args: T);
```

where `b` is parameterized on `T` which is parameterized on `K`. This is something that is not currently possible in TypeScript.

You could leave out the parameterization on `K` and have

```
export declare function b<T extends A[]>(...args: T);
```

however with the above TypeScript would be unable to enforce the type of your array. For example, it would allow `b([C, { doesnt_exist: '', e: true }]);` where you're missing the `d` property required in class `C` and `e` has the wrong type.

In order to do this properly in TypeScript you'll need to split the implementation of this function to two different functions that can each parameterize on only one type parameter.

```
type A<T extends new (...args: any) => any = any> = [T, Required<InstanceType<T>>];

function makeA<T extends new (...args: any) => any>(a: A<T>) {return a;}

function b<T extends A[]>(...args: T) { };

class C { d?: string; e?: number };

class F { g?: string; h?: number };

class I { j?: string; k?: number };

b(makeA([C, { d: 'hello', e: 4 }]), makeA([F, { g: 'string', h: 5 }]), makeA([I, { j: 'test', k: 6 }]));
```

So now `b` is parametric on `Array<T>` and `makeA` is parametric on `A<K>`. So combining the two you essentially get the higher kinded type you're looking for, albeit not as wieldy as it would be in Haskell, for instance.

It is harder to work with the `b` function this way, but you will get type safety on each argument of `b`.